# How to refers to the same ID in hierarchy table relationship

Tags: sql-server

I've been stuck for days solving this problem. I have three tables in SQL Server: Family, Funding, and bridging table Family_Funding. Family table list all family members in each family, like this:

**Family**

```
id          name                                               Parent_id
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           Father A                                           NULL
2           Son A                                              1
3           Daughter A                                         1
4           Father B                                           NULL
5           Mother B                                           NULL
6           Daughter B                                         4
```

The Funding table lists all funding programs each year. It also include the year in which those program was held.

**Funding**

```
id          name                                               year
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
1           Funding A                                          2010-01-14
2           Funding B                                          2011-11-14
3           Funding C                                          2014-01-01
4           Funding D                                          2016-01-01
5           Funding E                                          2018-01-01
```

Last one is bridging table which lists funding received by ONE (and only one) of the family members.

**Family_Funding**

```
id          Family_id   Funding_id
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           1           3
4           2           4
5           3           5
```

From the last table we can see that until year 2014, Family A gets the funding through the Father A, at year 2016 they gets the funding through Son A, and at year 2018 through Daughter A.

How do I achieve this result: 
I want to view all funding of Family A through its latest receiver, unfortunately I only get the result **Funding E** because the latest one to receive is through Daughter A. But because Daughter A is the member of family A, the result should includes other funding through Son A and Father A.

**Expected result**

```
Family_name   Funding A   Funding B   Funding C   Funding D   Funding E
-----------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
Daughter A    1           1           1           1           1
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a bit cleaner way, but it does get you what you're looking for. The main piece you should look at is the definition of the family (A, B, C...). The method I used was:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(fam.[Name],2)))
```

Here's the full code. I put the table data into table variables for the sake of this exercise.

```
DECLARE @Family TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ParentId BIGINT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Family
(Id, [Name], ParentId)
VALUES
(1,'Father A',NULL),
(2,'Son A',1),
(3,'Daughter A',1),
(4,'Father B',NULL),
(5,'Mother B',NULL),
(6,'Daughter B',4);

DECLARE @Funding TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Year] DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Funding
(Id, [Name], [Year])
VALUES
(1,'Funding A','2010-01-14'),
(2,'Funding B','2011-11-14'),
(3,'Funding C','2014-01-01'),
(4,'Funding D','2016-01-01'),
(5,'Funding E','2018-01-01');

DECLARE @FamilyFunding TABLE (
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FamilyId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FundingId BIGINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @FamilyFunding
(Id, FamilyId, FundingId)
VALUES
(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),
(3,1,3),
(4,2,4),
(5,3,5);

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    fam.[Name] AS FamilyName,
    fun.[Name] AS FundingName,
    fun.[Year],
    LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(fam.[Name],2))) AS Family,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(fam.[Name],2))) ORDER BY fun.[Year] DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM @FamilyFunding AS ff
INNER JOIN @Family AS fam
    ON ff.FamilyId = fam.Id
INNER JOIN @Funding AS fun
    ON ff.FundingId = fun.Id
),
FINAL AS (
SELECT
    a.Family,
    a.FamilyName AS MostRecentFamilyMember,
    a.[Year] AS MostRecentYear,
    b.FamilyName AS FamilyMember,
    b.FundingName,
    b.[Year],
    b.RowNumber
FROM CTE AS a
INNER JOIN CTE AS b
    ON a.Family = b.Family
WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
)

SELECT
    MostRecentFamilyMember,
    MAX([Funding A]) AS FundingA,
    MAX([Funding B]) AS FundingB,
    MAX([Funding C]) AS FundingC,
    MAX([Funding D]) AS FundingD,
    MAX([Funding E]) AS FundingE
FROM (
    SELECT
        f.Family,
        f.MostRecentFamilyMember,
        f.MostRecentYear,
        f.FamilyMember,
        f.FundingName,
        f.[Year],
        f.RowNumber,
        1 AS IsUsed
    FROM FINAL AS f
    ) AS b
PIVOT (
    MAX(IsUsed)
    FOR FundingName IN ([Funding A], [Funding B], [Funding C], [Funding D], [Funding E])
) AS p
GROUP BY
    MostRecentFamilyMember;
```

Comment: Thanks, but can it be used in general problems because I thought it used family name rather than ID?

Comment: It'd work best if there's a key in the database that states what family each person belongs to. Could you use a COALESCE(ParentId,Id) to determine family in a better way? It'd certainly be more solid. If that doesn't define a family, that's really going to be the weak spot.